# How to Wrap words in UILabel

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, interface-builder

I have a UILabel thats inside a Custom UITableViewCell, I am trying to get the word to wrap inside the UILabel.. But I am having some issues.

This is how the UITableViewCell looks in Interface Builder

[image]

The UILabel Label needs to wrap.. So in Interface Builder I have set the labels lines to 0 (which I think means multiple lines), and the line break to words.. which should wrap the words..

However now I think I have to put some code into something so that if the word wraps it expands the cell.. which I am not sure how to do.. I was wondering if anyone else here has experienced this issue before and could help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try increasing the height of the UILabel. It will only wrap words if it can fit the next line within the frame of the label.

Comment: I encreased the size in Interface builder, then changed Lines to 2, and then selected truncate tail in line breaks option, so the words will wrap to the second line and if it still dosn't fit then it will add a ... to the end.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be to do with the UITableViewCell height.  Perhaps you are not allowing for the cell to grow

Comment: yea I was wondering that also, I just didn't know what to look for.. going to go have a look at UItableViewCell height now... The main concern with that Is I don't know how to trigger it? how do you know if a word is going to wrap or not..

Comment: if you create a UILabel in memory with the text in it, you can use the textRectForBounds property to give you the size of the rectangle you will need to display the UILabel in the UITableViewCell