# UILabel won't wrap

Tags: ios

I'm having a problem with my iOS app and getting a UILabel in a UITableViewCell to wrap. The text shows but it will only display on one line.

Here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    UILabel *noteLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];

    NSDictionary *contact = [jsonResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    noteLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    noteLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    noteLabel.text = [contact objectForKey:@"note"];   
    return cell;
}
```

I believe the problem has something to do with this line:

```
UILabel *noteLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
```

I'm not sure how else to get the label from a tag and I think this line won't let me change the labels properties.

Comment: Have you stepped through in the debugger to make sure `noteLabel` is being properly returned and is not nil?

Comment: Have you tried increasing the height? Per this answer on about the topic, the UILabel won't wrap if it doesn't have the height to display the next lines. -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888802/how-to-wrap-words-in-uilabel

Comment: @George, The guy below answered with the same thing and gave an example. I tried his example but it didn't work.

Comment: @Keith I didn't see where he adjusted the height in his example. He's got width adjusted but it's the height that's the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to set the label's height:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    UILabel *noteLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];

    NSDictionary *contact = [jsonResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    noteLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    noteLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    noteLabel.text = [contact objectForKey:@"note"];

    //Note: adjust the proper width to be constrained to
    CGSize size = [noteLabel.text sizeWithFont:noteLabel.font forWidth:150 lineBreakMode:noteLabel.lineBreakMode];
    CGRect labelFrame = noteLabel.frame;
    labelFrame.size = size;
    noteLabel.frame = labelFrame; 

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: From everything I've read, you mainly just have to set the numberOfLines set to 0 and the line break set. I tried your code and it makde no difference.

Comment: I was able to get it to work with a few changes: CGRect labelFrame = noteLabel.frame;
    labelFrame.size.height = size.height;

    noteLabel.frame = labelFrame;
    [noteLabel sizeToFit];

Answer (score 0):

Time has moved on since 2012. In the current Xcode 5 world, height is automatically expanded for the multiple lines if numberOfLines is set to 0 in either code or in Interface Builder. One thing that can prevent the multiple lines from being displayed in this scenario is if there is an AutoLayout height constraint set, in Interface Builder or in code. In this scenario, it will look like a label that has been truncated, though in contrast to a truncated label it will not end with an ellipsis (...).

In order for AutoLayout to function as expected, you would not normally want to set a higher height to the UILabel, unless you knew that UILabel would always have multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

What made the difference for me was setting the label's preferredMaxLayoutWidth.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/preferredMaxLayoutWidth